# Java editing window menu bar

Tags: java, user-interface, window, menubar

I have a problem. You see, I want to add my own items to the **window** menu bar of my application, not add items to a JMenuBar. Like for example, look at the menu bar of the browser you are using. That type of menu bar. I know Java is run in a VM so you can't access too many things outside of the JVM, but is there any possible way that can be done? Whenever I search "Java menu bar" it comes up with just JMenuBar stuff and nothing about creating a window menu bar. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the JMenuBar look however you want. You just need to configure the menu bar and its menus appropriately.